# Load XML string array from path Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am building an Android app that loads a string array from and XML file in the resources folder using:

```
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arrayname);
```

My XML looks something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
<array name = "HSNames">
<item>My String</item>
<item>Another String</item>
</array>
</resources>
```

I want to be able to dynamically update the array by downloading a new XML file from the internet (Done).

**My question is, once I've saved the XML String array to**

```
 data/data/package/myarray.xml
```

**how do I load the array into memory?** I've already scoured Stack Overflow and Google with no luck. Do I have to parse the file manually using SAXParser or is there any other easier method? The path for my file would be:

```
getFilesDir()+"/myarray.xml"
```

Specifics would be awesome! :D Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you have to manually parse it, as once your APK has been compiled then the R.java file (where XML resources are referenced) has been built and compiled so you cannot add to it, nor will it automagically be added to.

Answer (score 1):

I've been very happy with the [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html).